# passing Temporary variables to reference arg in Constructor works. but not for functions in general. Why?

Tags: c++

Consider the following code.
Here, A a(B()) compiles even though the constructor is A(B& b);
But print(B()) does not work. But print is also declared as print(B& b);
Why this inconsistency?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class B{
    public:
            char b;
};

class A {
    public:
            B b;
            A(B& b);
            A() { }
};

A::A(B& b) {
    this->b = b;
}

void print(B& b) { }

int main(){
    print(B());
    A a(B());
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It compiles because it's not creating an instance of `A`. It's declaring a *function* named `a` that returns an `A` and receives one unnamed parameter of type pointer-to-function-returning-B. Since it's just a declaration, it compiles. If you're referred to `a` elsewhere in the code, you'd have seen additional problems. For why that's a function declaration instead of an object definition, the term to look up is *most vexing parse*.

Comment: This is so bloody bad! Does C++ even allow you do Declare a function INSIDE another funcion? Why does C++ allow that? Why would anyone need such a facility?

Comment: Yes, C++ does allow it. Obviously, since you just did. It's a declaration inside a function because it's a declaration everywhere else. Put that line inside a class declaration, and it's a member-function declaration. Put it outside anything else, and it's a function declaration. It's a function declaration no matter where you put it.

Comment: I think it is perfectly possible to modify the compiler to add the condition that if such a thing happened inside the definition of a function, it is not a function declaration, but a object declaration. I am surprised why they decided not to fix it.

Comment: @ajay: It's allowing it for backward compatibility: C allowed it. Nobody is happy about it, but not allowing it might break millions of lines of code.

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
A a(B());
```

isn't doing what you think.  It is actually parsed as a function declaration.  This is commonly referred to as the "[most vexing parse](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=439)" in C++ (there are many posts here about it, if you search for that phrase).

Answer (score 1):

You should not be passing a non-constant reference to a temporary, so the `print` statement should not compile. If you modify that reference in `print` to `const`, it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Where you are trying to call the constructor you are [actually declaring a function](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.19):

```
A a(B());
```

This declares `a` as a function returning `A` and taking as parameter a function pointer returning `B` and taking no parameters.

Actually trying to call the constructor results in an error, as expected:

```
A a = A(B());
```

> tst.cpp:32: error: no matching function for call to ‘A::A(B)’